# Regex to allow only in range 1-45 with single hyphen

Tags: javascript, regex

i tried to create a Regex to allow only in input in a range from below format with single hyphen.

Match

```
1-45
2-10
12-45
```

Not Match

```
1-
-2
1-45-
1,45
145
```

but most of the regex allow multiple hyphen

Comment: Does this have to be a regex? regex has no concept of numbers like 45, all it understands is a `"4"` followed by a `"5"`. And I have a feeling that you have the additional requirement that leftside < rightSide, correct?

Comment: "I want" is not a question. Please show your efforts, and what is holding you back to achieve this.

Comment: So you're trying to match ranges in the form _from_-_to_, but with _from_ and _to_ themselves restricted to the range 1...45?

Comment: This _may_ be _possible_ with regex, but it is certainly not a good use case for such a tool- you'd be better handling it programmatically in JavaScript.

Comment: Simply match `^(\d+)\-(\d+)$`, then do the rest in JS (checking 1 <= a, b <= 45 and a <= b).

Comment: I mean, sure. `^([1-9]|[1-3][0-9]|4[0-5])-([1-9]|[1-3][0-9]|4[0-5])$` will match two numbers between 1 and 45 with a hyphen between them (and capture the endpoints in the first two capture groups). But it won't validate that the second number is bigger than the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using JavaScript, I prefer a splitting approach here:

```js
var input = "12-45";
var pass = false;
if (/^\d+-\d+$/.test(input)) {
    var nums = input.split("-");
    if (nums[0] >= 1 && nums[0] <= 45 && nums[1] >= 1 && nums[1] <= 45) {
        pass = true;
    }
}

if (pass) {
    console.log("VALID");
}
else {
    console.log("INVALID");
}
```

Comment: I think the implication is that `nums[1]` also needs to be bigger than `nums[0]`.